# Different benchmarks for list copy in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, list, copy

I have a list in this way:
Lists in C++

```
list<int> p[15];
list<int> copy_of_p[15];
```

Lists in C#

```
list<int>[15] p;
list<int>[15] copy_of_p;
```

I tried to make 10000 copy from it in C# with this code

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
{
    copy_of_p[counter] = p[counter].toList();
}
```

it took about 10 MiliSecs

then I did the same thing in c++ with this code

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
{
    copy_of_p[counter] = p[counter];
}
```

and it took about 1200 MiliSecs

it means that there should be a way in c++ to copy the list at least as fast as C#. could you please guide me throw this?

P.S: I tried

```
copy(p.begin(), p.end(), copy_of_p[counter]);
```

but it made build error

Comment: Are you sure? The first bit of code you give tries to call `toList` on an integer as far as I can see, which shouldn't work. Meanwhile, the C++ STL list has a copy-constructor, so `copy_of_p = p` should be all you need.

Comment: `p[counter].toList()` I do not know C#, but using logic, I do not understand. p[counter] is int. What mean int::toList?

Comment: Note that C#s "list" type is similar to std::vector, not std::list.

Comment: @JonHanna: To me it looks like copy_of_p and p are ararys, and those don't have copy assignment in C++

Comment: 1200 ms for a 15-iteration loop? That can only be a measurement error.

Comment: jon and illusion p[0] is a list.

Comment: henk I ran it 10000 times. please read what I worte

Comment: I don't see why this question is voted down. The question seems to be clearly put... he has an array of lists in the first place. It is the usual SO practice of not reading before flagging/voting....

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know they are different. but I can copy 10000 list in C# in 10 mili. so it should be able to copy 10000 list in c++ in same time

Comment: Maybe you should first get your code and numbers straight? And then it's still not really on topic here.

Comment: @MHabibi: No. They are different data structures. To copy an N element std::list you need to do N allocations, to do that in C# you need 1 allocation. You should compare similar datastructures, not similarily named ones. Use std::vector in C++, it is the same as list in C#.

Comment: @PermanentGuest: This question is being voted down because the question and code make no sense. Neither the C# nor the C++ example will even compile. Taking a lot of guesses, I think the performance difference can be explained by the use of [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19) in C# and [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) in C++. `std::list` is a linked list, whereas .NET's `List` is an array list/dynamic array.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: they are straight. at least read What I wrote and then votedown.

Comment: @PermanentGuest: Downvote button reads "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I personally think the question is unclear, and I also fail to see the research effort.

Comment: @Mankarse: I compiled both of them in my computer. just definition in c# is a little bit different. and I put the definition if it is that hard to wirte;

Comment: `p[counter].toList()` have you declared your own Int32 extension method with a lower case `t` :)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I searched a lot. even I found some questions in this site that just wrote "I need a fast copy" and they have 10 votes. it seems something is wrong in this site. just voting for friends and this is a site for kiddos. they just closed my other account in same style. please grow up a little bit.

Comment: This is greatly confused by the fact that the OP has declared an _array of lists of integers_, not simply a list.

Comment: @MHabibi: Understanding what datastructures you are working with is the first step, and your question shows no effort in even trying to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that an stl-list<> is not the same as a C# List<>. stl-list is a doubly linked list while C# List<> stores the data in a contigious block of memory. Consequently stl-list<> copy operations are much faster.

C# List<> is equivalent to stl-vector<>

stl-list is equivalent to C# LinkedList<>

Answer (score 1):

A C# List is not actually a linked list. `std::list` is a linked list. Hence, you're comparing two very different operations. Secondly, the C++ code will call destructors and make memory available again for user, whereas a toy C# program will not perform any memory management or free any resources. For example, if instead you had `list<file>`, then the C++ program would close all the files and C# program would not.